# Cakephp 3.5 custom validation reading data from model

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

My code below works, the problem is that it's not efficient.

**Background**

Users can upload data from a spreadsheet to populate an app I am working on.
Several of the fields that they upload exist in tables and are used to populate select boxes or fields in the view as required. 
E.g. a countries table

```
+----+---------+
| id | country |
+----+---------+
|  1 | UK      |
|  2 | France  |
+----+---------+
```

It is not user friendly for the data in the spreadsheet to be IDs, so in the spreadsheet they write text 'UK', 'France', or can use the IDs if they so choose, but the IDs will be used if they ever edit the data via a web form within the app.

During the upload process, I arrange the data into an array where each entry is a new entity ready to be validated and then I pass it through Cake's validator process. For the fields described above I have a custom validator that checks that the ID exists or that the text is an exact match to the text field.

**Code**

The function that validates the data lives in the Uploads model, and is called after the data is arranged (not included here as not relevant):

```
// src/Model/Table/UploadsTable.php

protected function _validateData(array $data) {
    $Validator = TableRegistry::get('Laws')->getValidator('Upload');
    $validation = [];
    foreach( $data as $key => $row) {
        $validation[$key] = $Validator->errors($row);
    }
    return $validation;
}
```

The validator in the Laws model

```
// src/Model/Table/LawsTable.php

public function validationUpload(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator = $this->validationDefault($validator);

    $validator->setProvider("CustomValidator",\App\Model\Validation\CustomValidator::class);

    $validator
        ->scalar('country_id')
        ->requirePresence('country_id')
        ->add('country_id', 'country', [
            'rule' => 'country',
            'provider' => 'CustomValidator',
            'message' => 'Country value not in accepted list.'
        ]);   
}
```

In the custom validator

```
// src/Model/Validation/CustomValidator.php

class CustomValidator extends Validator
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function country($data) {
        $table = TableRegistry::get('Countries')->find()->toArray();
        $idKey = array_column($table, 'country','id');
        $fieldKey = array_column($table, 'id', 'country');
        if(in_array($data, $idKey) || in_array($data, $fieldKey)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;        
    }
}
```

**Problem**

The problem is that when a user uploads a spreadsheet, there might be 500 rows, and I have several fields that follow this method. When this script is executed I get a few thousand SQL queries because these static functions are called for every row & field.

The obvious solution to me is to remove the find() query out of the method, and find a way to pass the result to the method so the rest of the script works. But I have no idea how to extract them and where to put this kind of data gathering in the Cake workflow as they are being called statically.

Comment: can't you just run a script on the spreadsheet before the import process that stores the `country` column values into an array, compares it to your `countries` table and fire an alert like: "*Hey! Seems that some of your countries are misspelled or their IDs are non valid. Please check rows 20, 324 and 554*". This will cost you just one query for every column you need to validate

Comment: @arilia That is what I am trying to achieve, but while using Cake's validator. Otherwise I am validating twice and I've got to separate out these special cases.

Comment: in this case (but it's just MHO) I think that atomic validation is not appropriate. You can easily and quickly check 500 country names and identify the problematic rows in the spreadsheet before starting the insert process. Then you can insert all the 'good' row without the need of validating the country (but still validating other fields that don't need to run SQL queries)